# Include standardized coefficients in a Stargazer table

Tags: r, stargazer, coefficients

Forgive me as I'm brand new to R and if this is silly/easy, but I've been looking for hours but to no avail.
I have a series of GLM models, and I'd like to report the standardized/reparametrized coefficients for each alongside the direct coefficients in a Stargazer table. I created two separate models, one with standardized coefficients using the arm package.

```
require(arm)
model1 <- glm(...)
model1.2 <- standardize(model1)
```

Both models work, find and give the outputs I want, but 
I can't seem to figure out a way to get Stargazer to emulate this structure/look:
[http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.699&rep=rep1&type=pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwZNn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by asking stargazer to produce output for both models and making sure that the coefficients in the models have the same names so that stargazer knows that the standardized coefficient and the un-standardized coefficient should go on the same row.

The code below should help you get started.

```r
# generate fake data
x <- runif(100)
y <- rbinom(100, 1, x)

# fit the model
m1 <- glm(y~x, family = binomial())

# standardize it
m2 <- arm::standardize(m1)

# we make sure the coefficients have the same names in both models
names(m2$coefficients) <- names(m1$coefficients)

# we feed to stargazer
stargazer::stargazer(m1, m2, type = "text", 
                     column.labels = c("coef (s.e.)", "standarized coef (s.e.)"), 
                     single.row = TRUE)
#> 
#> ===========================================================
#>                              Dependent variable:           
#>                   -----------------------------------------
#>                                       y                    
#>                      coef (s.e.)    standarized coef (s.e.)
#>                          (1)                  (2)          
#> -----------------------------------------------------------
#> x                 4.916*** (0.987)     2.947*** (0.592)    
#> Constant          -2.123*** (0.506)      0.248 (0.247)     
#> -----------------------------------------------------------
#> Observations             100                  100          
#> Log Likelihood         -50.851              -50.851        
#> Akaike Inf. Crit.      105.703              105.703        
#> ===========================================================
#> Note:                           *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

You can usually figure out how to achieve what you want from the output by diving into the stargazer help file and looking at this helpful webpage https://www.jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer/

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was digging through all of the above and had no luck with what I was trying--I appreciate the extremely fruitful answer!!